# Why are my child nodes not be added?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
  if (number_layers === 4)
  {
    var mat = document.createElement("mat");
    var imgsrc = document.createElement("imgsrc");
    imgsrc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(default_matte_source));
    mat.appendChild(imgsrc);

    var total_size = document.createElement("total_size");
    total_size.appendChild(document.createTextNode(7.5));
    mat.appendChild(total_size);

    var cpu = document.createElement("cpu");
    cpu.appendChild(document.createTextNode(12));
    mat.appendChild(cpu);

    var cid = document.createElement("cid");
    cid.appendChild(document.createTextNode(default_matte_cid));
    mat.appendChild(cid);

    mattes[3] = mat;
  }
  console.log(mattes);
```

When I check the console there is a mat in the 4th position, but it has no child nodes. Why is that?

Comment: mat[3] is not the third element in the array (not the third position)! arrays in js are zero-based...

Comment: I'm seeing the `childNodes` property of that element just fine in the console, with 4 elements. They're not in the *array*, of course, but they wouldn't be.

Comment: Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/zlmih